# Select column Group By another column in same table Laravel 10

Tags: sql, postgresql, eloquent, laravel-10

I have a class **myClss** in Laravel 10 like this:

| Type | Name |
| --- | --- |
| type 1 | name 2 |
| type 2 | name 1 |
| type 1 | name 3 |
| type 3 | name 4 |
| type 3 | name 5 |

i want to return the data in view.blade like this **List** :

- type 1

  - name 2
  - name 3
- type 2

  - name 1
- type 3

  - name 4
  - name 5

I've tried to use Eloquent with GroupBy method but coudn't figured out how to achieve that with one query.
I also tried with sql :

```
select type, name from table myclass
group by type
```

But didn't get what i want , cause group by work with aggregate methods (ie: count ...).

What i'm thinking is to return only the types , and then in the view.blade the user has to click on differents types to get the related names ( like Filter )

**My question :**

is there any esay way i can do it with only one query ( ***Laravel or SQL*** ) and from the first load of the view.blade,  like the List above ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return the result like a nested list, you need to use the `string_agg` function on postgres to concatenate. the names grouped by type -

```sql
SELECT
    type,
    STRING_AGG(name, E'\n') AS names
FROM
    myclass
GROUP BY
    type;
```

on the laravel side, using DB facade -

```php
$results = DB::select('
    SELECT
        type,
        STRING_AGG(name, E\'\n\') AS names
    FROM
        myclass
    GROUP BY
        type
');
```

and for the blade view, you need to iterate through the results to display the data like -

```php
@foreach($results as $row)
    <p>{{ $row->type }}</p>
    @foreach(explode('\n', $row->names) as $name)
        <p>{{ $name }}</p>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```